# Which sets can be built in the bag (all the parts are in one bag)?

Tags: sets, packaging, bag-build

I've had the chance to participate in some "build in the bag" contests at some events. The idea is simple: each contestant gets a small set (usually provided by LEGO for the occasion), and everybody tries to build the set at the same time.

The trick is, the contestants may not open the bag but should build the model inside it. The first to finish wins some additional prize. You can also up the ante, [PLUG](http://www.plug.pt/) did for example [do this underwater](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1lDwVtjZyE).

However, this does require that all parts of the set are in exactly one transparent polybag. Small racers sets (the one in plastic boxex with a round top) are usually suitable, but we've had a club event where we wanted to do that and there was no polybag (the first to open his box spilled the contents on the ground), so we had to find some other contest (I think we ended up with one-handed build or build without plan).

So my question is, which sets are known to have all parts in one polybag? Is there any way to find out?

Comment: How about 'What sets can be bag-built?' for a title?

Comment: [Looks like there was a custom bag](http://legospace.com/en-us/Gallery/Default.aspx) built for the ISS model that was taken up to the station, which probably doesn't count: [Satoshi Furukawa with the LEGO Brick Kit aboard the ISS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xyI8r.jpg)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ones I know of:

- [8072 - Sea Jet](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8072-1)
- [8400 - Space Speeder](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8400-1)
- [8398 - BBQ Stand](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8398-1)
- [5611 - Public Works](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=5611-1)
- [5762 - Mini Plane](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=5762-1)
- [7241 - Fire Car](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7241-1)
- [8130 - Terrain Crusher](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=8130-1)
- [5618 - Troll Warrior](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=5618-1)
- to be continued...

In addition, some LEGO Creator sets, with only partly transparent bags are possible to build in bag, like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TgNSRCUMNc) shows - but it gets *a lot* harder.

Rather then listing all of the sets, I'd go by the general rule that sets that are 9.5cm x 9.5cm x 4.5cm or smaller are in one bag (or just in the box). The [Court Jester (7953)](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7953-1) for example, is one exception in that the [Jester hat](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=62537pb03) is packaged separately.

Comment: I suppose we can exclude bigger sets (or sets with more than x pieces, with x to define), but there are a lot of small sets (such as the one you mention) which don't qualify, and that's a problem.

Comment: Some of the bigger sets will have one bag per part of the set, for instance [this train set where the platform can be build from one bag](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6012198.pdf).

Comment: There are some "advent calendar" sets (as in, a box containing 24 polybags behind "doors" labeled 1 through 24), I have done some bag builds with one of those.

Answer (score 6):

Brickset has a feature to allow you to search sets by tags, which is incredibley useful as you can find a [full list of Polybag sets](http://brickset.com/sets/tag-polybag).

The list can be sorted in various ways. You can sort by year (descending) to find the newest sets that might still be available to buy, or which polybags have the most pieces and will probably be the most challenging.

Some of these are simply bulk bags of bricks which you can ignore.

---

The three largest polybag sets are limited edition from the Master Builder Academy series. These polybags were originally only available in the US as part of the LEGO Master Builder Academy subscription.

The largest polybag set is the [#40178 Exclusive VIP Set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40178-1) released in 2017 with 205 pieces and two minifigures.

[image]